# ActiveRecord syntax to test for dates in two different columns Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 3.23
```

I have a payments table with the following two columns in it:

```
created_at
paid_at
```

I need an ActiveRecord query, to select the rows, where:

```
paid_at >= created_at + 30.days
```

I can't figure out the syntax.

The following syntax works:

```
where = "paid_at > DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY)"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("#{query}")
```

And from the responses, I understand that the only way to do it, to directly execute a MySQL query. The only problem here, seems that the return object, is not an ActiveRecord object, but a regular array of hashes

Comment: If you want to do this effectively you're going to have to use the date functions in your database to evaluate the condition there. In Postgres you would do something like `where("paid_at >= created_at  + interval '30 days'")`. This is not actually something thats part of ActiveRecords query interface as it differs extremely between dbs.

Comment: Also `Payment.where(paid_at: 30.days.from_now.to_date)` just "works" if you definition of "works" is that it did not blow up. It just gets records from exactly that day. If you want to get records from a given span (which is known beforehand and not evaluated per row) you need to use a range. `Payment.where(paid_at: 5.days.ago..30.days.ago)`

Comment: @max Yes, this sort of syntax works, but does not resolve the issue. I was using that as an illustration

Comment: If you want an actual answer should update the question with what RDBMS you are using and an example of the data and the expected output. Thats far more useful.